# How to SELECT rows from table A where JOIN with table B matches condition 1 or doesn't exist for condition 2

Tags: mysql, database

I came upon a problematic query to be made on my two tables.

My tables can be simplified to:

Table A:

```
id 
(PRIMARY KEY - id)
```

Table B:

```
id (matches id from table A)
shop
active
(PRIMARY KEY id, shop)
```

---

Now I want to select rows from Table A for shops 2 and 3 where active = false, or row for those shops doesn't exist at all.

So for example I have:

```
Table 1:
(1)
(2)
(3)

Table 2:
(1, 1, true)
(1, 2, false)
(2, 3, false)
(1, 3, true)
(3, 2, false)
(3, 3, false)
```

I should get id 2 and 3.
2 - because row for shop 2 doesnt exist and row for shop 3 has active = false.
3- because it has both rows with active = false

Comment: I cant follow your question logic, too complicated and your sample doesnt match your description  Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

Really difficult to work out what you mean as you appear to be mixing up whether it is id or shop on tableB that you want to match on. And your sample data doesn't seem to match up with your description.

However it looks like a LEFT OUTER JOIN, and checking for no matched records in the WHERE clause. Put a check for active in the ON clause of the join to exclude match which are active as well as those that do not match:-

```
SELECT TableA.id
FROM TableA
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB
ON TableA.id = TableB.shop
AND TableB.active = true
WHERE TableB.id IS NULL
```

EDIT - following your comment to clarify the columns, this should do it.

It does a LEFT OUTER JOIN from TableA to TableB where the active field is true. Any matches mean that record is rejected. This means you will only get a record back where either there is no record on TableB for that id, or there is a match on id but active is set to false.

```
SELECT DISTINCT TableA.id
FROM TableA
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB
ON TableA.id = TableB.id
AND TableB.active = true
WHERE TableB.id IS NULL
```

Comment: id in TableA is matching id in TableB.
Shop and Active are additional columns in TableB.

Now i want to find ids from TableA where row in TableB exists for shop 2 with active = false, or row doesnt exist for shop 2 at all.

Tables are joined on TableA.id = TableB.id